# Airflow TaskGroups - adding another taskgroup that waits for the other taskgroups to finish running

Tags: airflow

I have 3 tasksgroups currently, they run independently from one another, but I want to add another one (QUERY) that runs after the other task groups finish running:

```
    with TaskGroup(group_id='query') as QUERY:
        affiliates_query = SnowflakeQueryOperator()

t1
t2
t3
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
    t1
    t2
    t3
[t1,t2,t3] >> QUERY
```

Comment: I think you might need dummy task in middle? eg. `[t1,t2,t3] >> dummy >> QUERY`

Comment: Could you please add your code and share image of how you want the workflow to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting the TaskGroups into another overall TaskGroup and referencing the name of that TaskGroup in the workflow.

```
with dag:
    with TaskGroup(group_id='big_tent') as big_tent:
        with TaskGroup(group_id='t1') as t1:
        # Do something
        with TaskGroup(group_id='t2') as t2:
        # Do something
        with TaskGroup(group_id='t3') as t3:
        # Do something

    with TaskGroup(group_id='query') as QUERY:
        affiliates_query = SnowflakeQueryOperator()
    big_tent >> QUERY
```

I used a for loop but it should return the same results. A Dummy Operator between them won't matter but it does help when reading the DAG by separating the processes.